# Viewpager, compatibility pack, ice cream sandwich and exporting signed application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I saw this [ViewPager, compatibility package and ice cream sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928762/viewpager-compatibility-package-and-ice-cream-sandwich) and that [Does the Android ICS API have a native equivalent to ViewPager support lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958013/does-the-android-ics-api-have-a-native-equivalent-to-viewpager-support-lib) questions which are similar to mine, but not really what I want to ask.

The scenario is similar, I have a ICS only appplication and I'm applying the ViewPager on it (I've already avoided the FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter to not fall into the fragmentmanager from the compatibility package problem).

The problem is when I export my signed application, I notice on the proguard mapping that it also exported all the fragment stuff from the support library, such as:

```
 android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb -> android.support.v4.app.a:
 android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord -> android.support.v4.app.b:
 android.support.v4.app.BackStackState -> android.support.v4.app.BackStackState:
 android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout -> android.support.v4.app.u:
```

So, then I'm not sure, will my app be applying the support library objects all around instead of using the nice system wide fragment manager? How can I block it from doing so?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer would be that if you look at the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)** you would see that the package containing the viewpager is **android.support.v4.view** so, when you use the viewpager it needs to load all the classes that the viewpager uses and some of them are inside the same package. Hope this helps.